# 24 hour clock in Powershell end the day with 00 or 24

Tags: powershell, time, clock

all.

I am conditioning my code (in Powershell) to read either "Good morning" or "Good afternoon" depending on the 24-hour clock. However, I am unfamiliar with the clock.

Do you know whether Powershell ends the clock at 00:00 or 24:00 at midnight? Thanks.

Comment: [DateTime]::MaxValue => 23:59:59

Comment: I did not get that, but I know what you mean :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clock interval is >= 00 && < 24

i.e:

```
Max value is: 23:59:59
Min value is: 00:00:00
```